# SQL ordering by COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables with the attached columns.

```
tags
 -t_id (PRIMARY)
 -pg
tag_refs
 -t_id
 -bp_id
```

Now I trying to write a MySQL query that returns the total number of tags ordered by how popular they are - which, in this case, means how many times the unique t_id is represented in the tag_refs table.

I assume this would be a joined query, which has to return a list from the tags table where I can use the pg column to output the name/title of each tag only once, ordered by which is used the most.

I tried the following query which returns only one row, but which seems to be ordered as I want it to be.

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
JOIN tag_refs ON tags.t_id = tag_refs.t_id
ORDER BY COUNT(tag_refs.t_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do your aggregation in the SELECT like this:

```
SELECT tags.pg, COUNT(tag_refs.t_id) AS tag_count
FROM tags INNER JOIN tag_refs ON tags.t_id = tag_refs.t_id
GROUP BY tag.pg
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing `Group by` Clause

```
SELECT 
tag_refs.t_id,  COUNT(tag_refs.t_id) 
FROM 
    tags 
JOIN 
    tag_refs 
ON 
    tags.t_id = tag_refs.t_id 
group by tag_refs.t_id
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(tag_refs.t_id) 
DESC
```

read a little about this clause [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm)